# How to use multiple thread for multiple circle animation?

Tags: java, multithreading, geometry

I already paint multiple circles and I want them to move to right simultaneously with different threads. So I have to use multiple threads. However, when I run the program, it repaints circles again and again. I actually know where the problem is but I don't know how to solve it. Here is my code:

**Circles.java:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class Circles extends JPanel {
    private int x,y,r,s;
    private Color c;
    private Random ran;

    public Circles() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        ran = new Random();
        x = ran.nextInt(600)+5;
        y = ran.nextInt(600)+5;
        r = ran.nextInt(100)+20;
        s = ran.nextInt(10)+5;
        c = new Color(ran.nextInt(255),ran.nextInt(255),ran.nextInt(255));
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public Color getC() {
        return c;
    }
    public int getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void move(int speed) {
        x = x+speed;
    }
}
```

**Game.java:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    private static Circles myCircle;
    private static int numberOfCircle;
    private Random ran;
    private static ArrayList<Circles> circleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Game() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(700,700);
        setTitle("Game");
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
        System.out.println(t.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.paint(g);
        for(int i=0; i<numberOfCircle; i++) {
            myCircle = new Circles();
            g.setColor(myCircle.getC());
            g.fillOval(myCircle.getX(), myCircle.getY(), myCircle.getR(), myCircle.getR());
            circleList.add(myCircle);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game(); 
        numberOfCircle = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
                for(int i=0; i<numberOfCircle; i++) {
                    myCircle.move(circleList.get(i).getS());
                }
                repaint();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think you missed telling which is the problem and where it is. By the way you don't need a thread per circle to have them moving at the same time. Ussually this is just an illusion acomplished by treating all circles, one by one in an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention that. The problem is that I am calling `repaint()` method in `while` loop and this paints my circles again with different points. But I thought that to be able to move them to right, I have to repaint all circles.

About multithread, yeah I actually figured it out later but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: To animate without leaving crap behind, you need to get rid of the previous frame as you draw the next.

Comment: One of the problems I see is that you are adding a new circle to the list of circles each time you call repaint. If it is a fixed number of circles you should set them up before the loop starts and then just get them from the list and update their position or what ever changes.

Comment: Yes, I add circles to the list. Please correct me if I am wrong. If even I fix the number of circles in my ArrayList, are you sure that it won't repaint the circles again? Because, yes maybe it wont add more circles to the list but it will still repaint them I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you are calling paint, you are creating new circles inside of paint method again and again, carry out your initialization outside of paint to some init method,

```
 @Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);
    for (Circles myCircle:circleList
         ) {
        g.setColor(myCircle.getC());
        g.fillOval(myCircle.getX(), myCircle.getY(), myCircle.getR(), myCircle.getR());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game(); 
    numberOfCircle = 5;

    for(int i=0; i<numberOfCircle; i++) {
        myCircle = new Circles();
        circleList.add(myCircle);
    }

}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
            for (Circles myCircle:circleList
                 ) {
                myCircle.move(myCircle.getS());
            }
            repaint();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is working? Because it didn't paint any circle.

Comment: Yes, I run this I see one circle going from left to right.

Comment: Yes, but I want to do it with more than 1 circle.

Comment: Corrected for multiple Circles.